# jQuery - How to show/hide multiple DIVs with child DIVs

Tags: jquery, show-hide

I've got a markup as follows (code modified from http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/srg6g/):

```
<div id="maps">
    <div class="map-box"><h2>London &amp; South East</h2><a href="#london"><img src="http://dummyimage.com/100x100/000/fff&text=London" /></a></div>
    <div class="map-box"><h2>South West, Ireland and Wales</h2><a href="#south-west"><img src="http://dummyimage.com/100x100/000/fff&text=South+West" /></a></div>    
    <div class="map-box"><h2>South Central &amp; Home Counties</h2><a href="#south-central"><img src="http://dummyimage.com/100x100/000/fff&text=South+Central" /></a></div>
    <div class="map-box"><h2>North England, Northern Ireland &amp; Scotland</h2><a href="#north"><img src="http://dummyimage.com/100x100/000/fff&text=North" /></a></div>
    <div class="map-box"><h2>Midlands</h2><a href="#midlands"><img src="http://dummyimage.com/100x100/000/fff&text=Midlands" /></a></div>
</div>
<br /><br/>
<div id="areas">
    <div id="london">
        <div>content london 1</div>
        <div>content london 2</div>
    </div>
    <div id="south-west">
        <div>content south west 1</div>
        <div>content south west 2</div>
    </div>
    <div id="south-central">
        <div>content south central 1</div>
        <div>content south central 2</div>
    </div>
    <div id="north">
        <div>content north 1</div>
        <div>content north 2</div>
    </div>
    <div id="midlands">
        <div>content midlands 1</div>
        <div>content midlands 2</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And my JavaScript code looks like as follows:

```
$(".map-box a").click(function(e) {
    $("#areas div").hide();
    $(this.hash).show();
    e.preventDefault();
});
$("#areas div").not("#london, #london div").hide();
```

When a user clicks on a image, I'd like to hide what's currently displayed and show both  contents associated for that image but this doesn't work.

e.g.,

- User clicks on "South West"
- Display both "content south west 1" and "content south west 2"

Would anybody be able to tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the selector on this line:

```
$("#areas div").hide();
```

This is selecting and hiding all div elements that are descendants of the "#areas" div, which includes not just the divs with ids like "london", etc., but those divs' children too. Then later when you show a div based on an id like "london" its child divs with the actual content remain hidden.

Try this instead:

```
$("#areas > div").hide();
```

And similarly for the line that hides them initially:

```
$("#areas > div").not("#london, #london div").hide();​
```

That will hide only the divs that are direct children of "#areas". While they are hidden their children will be hidden too, but then when you show one its children will automatically appear with it.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/7s5nP/